# Which package managers allow to download binary packages through torrent protocol?

Tags: package-management, bittorrent

I looked to guides for portage and paludis and didn't found this feature. Is there any such package manager in other linux distributions ?

UPD (from #paludis@freenode):
Q:is it possible to setup paludis to download pbins with torrent protocol ?
A:Yes. Configure the correct stuff in the repo.conf, and create a dotorrent fetcher

Comment: http://benjaminkerensa.com/2012/05/30/package-updates-over-bittorrent-protocol

Comment: apt-dht -> apt-p2p

Comment: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-145622.html

Answer (score 3):

Debian once had something called `debtorrent`, but it was removed from unstable on 2nd December 2013. See the Debian bug report:
[RM: debtorrent -- No activity in years](https://bugs.debian.org/730459).

As the initial posting on the report says:

> All interest in debtorrent seems to have disappeared a long while
>   back.  The mailing lists have fell silent and there isn't even a
>   tracker up any  more, so it is effectively useless.
>
> Removing it will save poor saps like me time trying to work out why
>   the  tracker is not responding.

It's sad, really.