# How to download pbins with paludis through torrent protocol?

Tags: package-management, gentoo, bittorrent

I read the following in [Which package managers allow to download binary packages through torrent protocol?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245814)
:

> Configure the correct stuff in the repo.conf, and create a dotorrent fetcher"

How can I configure paludis to download pbins via the torrent protocol?